# Destructor called form inappropriate library

Tags: c++, linux, g++, siebel

**Here's the code:**

foo.h

```cpp
extern "C" {
    int  sdq_init_connector(const SSchar* path);
}
```

foo.cxx

```cpp
int sdq_init_connector(const SSchar* path)
{
    Logger log(LOG_DEBUG, "sdq_init_connector");

    /*
    here goes some not so relevant code
    */

    log.write("Here be dragons");

    return 0;
 }
```

And there is Logger class, that is being used in foo, nothing interesting, constructor(char * message), destructor() and write(char * message).

**Problem summary:**

When I call libfoo.so from test appliance  it work flawlessly but when it is getting called from production system after function sdq_init_connector return it SEGFAULTs backtrace below

```cpp
#10 <signal handler called>
#11 0x583d7fee in Node::~Node() () from /opt/siebel/sba81/siebsrvr/mw/lib/libtl.so
#12 0x583de09a in Logger::~Logger() () from /opt/siebel/sba81/siebsrvr/mw/lib/libtl.so
#13 0x6c86e001 in sdq_init_connector () from /opt/siebel/sba81/siebsrvr/lib/libfoo.so
```

Note the #12 there is another library with same object name. Why is destructor from some foreign library called for my internal object?

Comment: Lack of namespaces means that the symbols have the same name. Maybe one of them is weak? I suggest running nm -aC|grep Logger on both libraries.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case. Added namespace to my logger implementation. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signatures of destructors for Logger object were same indeed.

How it was:

```
[root@baz ~]# nm -aC /opt/siebel/sba81/siebsrvr/mw/lib/libtl.so| grep Logger
0001a0b0 W Logger::~Logger()
0001a070 W Logger::~Logger()

[root@baz ~]# nm -aC /opt/siebel/sba81/siebsrvr/lib/libfoo.so| grep Logger
000251b8 T Logger::~Logger()
000257ac T Logger::~Logger()
00025d90 T Logger::~Logger()
```

How it now:

```
[root@baz ~]# nm -aC /opt/siebel/sba81/siebsrvr/lib/libfoo.so| grep Logger
00025288 T Foo::Logger::~Logger()
0002587c T Foo::Logger::~Logger()
00025e60 T Foo::Logger::~Logger()
```

I've added namespace to my library, and it solved this problem.